# Ansible playbook not woking with multivalued lists

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to write a playbook that creates multiple users but it does not work when i put my variables in a list form.

### Not working playbook

```
[root@ansible-master playbooks]# cat users_list_new.yml
---
users:
  - username:
      - amba
      - ruchita

[root@ansible-master playbooks]# cat multi_users_new.yml
---
- name: Creating the multi users with a new approach
  hosts: california
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - users_list_new.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Create the user
      user:
        name: "{{ item.username[0] }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
```

It only creates the first user because I have put the subscript 0 in the user module. My question is how we can create a loop over username . For instance I modified my playbook but it didn't work

```
---
- name: Creating the multi users with a new approach
  hosts: california
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - users_list_new.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Create the user
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users.username }}"
```

It threw below error when I ran the playbook

```
PLAY [Creating the multi users with a new approach] ********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.128.0.5]

TASK [Create the user] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.128.0.5]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'username'"}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.128.0.5                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

[root@ansible-master playbooks]#
```

Please help me to figure out the solution

****EDIT ****
Suppose I want to create two users . What is the best practice of variable declaration ?

### First Approach

```
users:
  - username:
      - amba
      - ruchita
  - shell:
      - /bin/bash
      - /bin/ksh
```

Second Approach

```
users:
  - username: amba
    shell: /bin/bash
  - username: ruchita
    shell: /bin/bash
```

Comment: I *think* (can't verify atm, not at work) that you just need to *flatten* the outer list:  get rid of the hyphen in front of username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your variable structure `users` contains a list not a dict so you cant access `username` as a key of it since its a list not a dict. You would need to access as `users[0]` to get access to the list of usernames.

```yaml
---

- name: Creating the multi users with a new approach
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - users_list_new.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Create the user
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users[0].username }}"
```

```bash
TASK [Create the user] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 23 October 2022  08:47:41 +0100 (0:00:07.567)       0:00:08.179 ******** 
changed: [localhost] => (item=amba)
changed: [localhost] => (item=ruchita)

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**BEFORE**

```bash
root@ff9c44b4c94f:/local# id amba; id ruchita
id: ‘amba’: no such user   
id: ‘ruchita’: no such user
```

**AFTER**

```bash
root@ff9c44b4c94f:/local# id amba; id ruchita
uid=8257(amba) gid=8257(amba) groups=8257(amba)
uid=8258(ruchita) gid=8258(ruchita) groups=8258(ruchita)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But what is the best practice. Suppose I want to create username,shell and home directory. Shall I create three separate lists of lists or shall I create three lists only with dict values (username: amba, shell: /bin/bash)..See the edited question

Comment: Personally i prefer the second approach as you can then just do things like `shell: item.shell` as you iterate over each user

Comment: Create a dictionnary of dictionnaries e.g. `users: {alfred: {shell: /bin/bash, home: /home/alfred}, mary: {shell: /bin/zsh, home: /alternate_home/mary}}`. Then loop on it with the [dict lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dict_lookup.html): `key` will be your username, `value` contains the options for that user (i.e. `item.value.shell`, `item.value.home`). Note that the example in the linked doc is sticking exactly to your actual concern.

Comment: If you don't like that approach, an other solution is to create a list of dicts: `users: [{name: alfred, shell: /bin/bash, home: /home/alfred}, {name: mary, shell: /bin/zsh, home: /alternatehome/mary}]`. Then in your loop you can address `item.name`, `item.shell` and `item.home`.